# Why is total probability, the integration of (f(x) dx)?

Tags: calculus, probability, graphing-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable and $f(x)$ be its probability mass function. 
Since summation of all the probabilities equals one, it is mentioned that integration of $[f(x)\cdot dx]$ equals one.

But is it conveying the same idea ?

The integration actually gives the area beneath the curve, which need not be equal to one. Sum of probabilities equals one means that the sum of all the values (images) of $f(x)$, and not the infinitesimal areas, equals one. Right ?

Is my understanding faulty ?
Please explain.

Comment: If $f$ is a probability distribution function, then the area below it will definitely be $1$. I don't know how you define the "sum" of all values of $f$, when there is infinitely many of them. By the way, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please remember to use MathJax notation in your posts

Comment: $f(x)$ does not mean the probability of getting $X = x$, see this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable

Comment: @caverac Good point! The OP may be confusing probability distribution function with probability mass function

Answer (score 3):

The "probability density function" for $X$ is defined by the property
$$
\text{Prob}(a \le X \le b) = \int_a^b f(x)\;dx
$$
whenever $a \le b$.  (Of course, this does not exist in some cases, for example when $X$ is a discrete random variable.)
Then limits show us that (since all values of $X$ are real numbers)
$$
1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\;dx
$$

Comment: So this doesn't hold for discrete random variables. Am I right ?